# Is there a Map implementation with listeners for Java?

Tags: java

I would like a Map implementation in which i could add listeners for put() events.

Is there anything like that in the standard or any 3rd party libraries?

Comment: Write a MapListenerAdaptor class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not aware of any standard or 3rd party, but it is easy, just create a class which wraps another Map and implements the Map interface:

```
public class MapListener<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {

    private final Map<K, V> delegatee;

    public MapListener(Map<K, V> delegatee) {
        this.delegatee = delegatee;
    }

    // implement all Map methods, with callbacks you need.

}
```

Comment: Instead of `implements Map<K, V>`, I think it's easier to use `extends Abstract Map<K, V>`. (But I agree about structuring it as a wrapper that delegates to another map.)

Comment: Guava's ForwardingMap is basically exactly this -- it forwards all the methods to the delegate, and then you can override them to taste.

Comment: That is what i thought, just fishing for reusable code before writing my own :)

Comment: There's a problem here, which is that some Maps, like an LRU map, might call its own "remove" method, bypassing the delegator. So an add() call to the delegator calls the add() method of the LRU map, which causes a remove() call to the LRU map, and hence not fire an event for the listener.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't think LRU maps are the problem.  A call to put( ) might internally call remove/add to move the entry in the list, but listener would still be informed of the put() call on MapListener; an entry was added/updated in the map, it wasn't removed - internal details aside.  The _larger issue_ is an `Iterator` over the map can remove entries and the listener would not be informed; similarly, an `Iterator` over the `entrySet()` could be used to modify entries without the listener being informed.

Comment: @AJNeufeld Obviously, it depends on what you want it to do, but if you want one listener to be allowed to be notified when an object is out of the map, this information is problematic.

Comment: There is also `Map.Entry.setValue` calls to this method will not notify the listeners.

Comment: I believe you must implement a wrapper for `entrySet` to, which wraps the original `entrySet` and fires proper events.

Comment: @AJNeufeld You could probably solve that by overriding the iterator() method and wrap that, too. (Of course, its' more complicated than that. Map doesn't have an `iterator()' method, so you would have to override methods like `keySet()` and wrap the returning `Set`'s `iterator()` method. But it's doable.)

Answer (score 4):

Season to taste. This is representative, not normative. Of course it has issues.

```
public class ListenerMap extends HashMap {

    public static final String PROP_PUT = "put";
    private PropertyChangeSupport propertySupport;

    public ListenerMap() {
        super();
        propertySupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }

    public String getSampleProperty() {
        return sampleProperty;
    }

    @Override
    public Object put(Object k, Object v) {
        Object old = super.put(k, v);
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_PUT, old, v);
        return old;
    }

        public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertySupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertySupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Comment: Extending is not a good thing for this requirement, I believe creating a wrapper for every map is much better.

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh what do you mean by "wrapper for every map"?

Comment: A wrapper which accepts any map implementation as an argument, so the default behavior of the map remains as it was.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example of a map which fires property change events on put and remove. The implementation is divided in two classes:

> ListenerModel

Contains the methods related to adding and removing the change listeners and also a method for firing the property changes.

> ListenerMap

Extends ListenerModel and implementes the java.util.Map interface by delegation. It fires the property changes in the put and remove method only. It would make sense to fire the properties on other methods like e.g. clear(), putAll().

**ListenerModel**

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

public class ListenerModel {

    private final PropertyChangeSupport changeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        changeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        changeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    protected void firePropertyChange(String propertyName, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        changeSupport.firePropertyChange(propertyName, oldValue, newValue);
    }
}
```

**ListenerMap**

```
import java.util.*;

public class ListenerMap<K, V> extends ListenerModel implements Map<K, V> {

    public static final String PROP_PUT = "put";

    public static final String REMOVE_PUT = "remove";

    private Map<K, V> delegate = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        delegate.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return delegate.containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return delegate.containsValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        return delegate.entrySet();
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        return delegate.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return delegate.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        return delegate.keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        V oldValue = delegate.put(key, value);
        firePropertyChange(PROP_PUT, oldValue == null ? null : new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, oldValue),
                new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, value));
        return oldValue;
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        delegate.putAll(m);
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        V oldValue = delegate.remove(key);
        firePropertyChange(REMOVE_PUT, oldValue == null ? null : new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, oldValue),
                null);
        return oldValue;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return delegate.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        return delegate.values();
    }
}
```

Here is a JUnit 4 test:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNull.nullValue;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

/**
 * Created by Gil on 01/07/2017.
 */
public class ListenerMapTest {

    private ListenerMap<String, String> map;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        map = new ListenerMap<>();
    }

    @Test
    public void whenPut_ShouldFireTrigger() throws Exception {
        boolean[] fired = {false};
        Map.Entry<String, String>[] listenEntry = new Map.Entry[1];
        boolean[] checkNull = {true};
        PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener = evt -> {
            if (ListenerMap.PROP_PUT.equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                if(checkNull[0]) {
                    assertThat(evt.getOldValue(), is(nullValue()));
                }
                else {
                    Map.Entry<String, String> oldValue = (Map.Entry<String, String>) evt.getOldValue();
                    assertThat(oldValue.getKey(), is("k1"));
                    assertThat(oldValue.getValue(), is("v1"));
                }
                listenEntry[0] = (Map.Entry<String, String>) evt.getNewValue();
                fired[0] = true;
            }
        };
        map.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyChangeListener);
        map.put("k1", "v1");
        assertThat(fired[0], is(true));
        assertThat(listenEntry[0].getKey(), is("k1"));
        assertThat(listenEntry[0].getValue(), is("v1"));
        checkNull[0] = false;
        map.put("k1", "v2");
    }

    @Test
    public void whenRemove_ShouldNotFire() throws Exception {
        boolean[] fired = {false};
        PropertyChangeListener propertyChangeListener = evt -> {
            fired[0] = true;
        };
        map.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyChangeListener);
        map.put("k1", "v1");
        assertThat(fired[0], is(true));
        fired[0] = false;
        map.removePropertyChangeListener(propertyChangeListener);
        map.put("k2", "v2");
        assertThat(fired[0], is(false));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Java has an javafx.collections.[ObservableMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableMap.html) interface in their JavaFX library.

ObservableMap implementations can be obtained in the javafx.collections.[FXCollections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html) class.

- The [observableHashMap()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableHashMap--) static method creates an Observable HashMap
- The [observableMap(Map<K,V> map)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableMap-java.util.Map-) static method creates a Observable forwarding map backed by the map instance passed into the method.

Callers register an [MapChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/MapChangeListener.html)  with the ObservableMap instance to receive onChanged events.  In the onChanged event handler, the [MapChangeListener.Change](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/MapChangeListener.Change.html) method parameter can be interrogated to determine if a put occurred.

Comment: This should be stdlib :)

Comment: Java FX was a part of J2SE in java 8.  :)   For the latest java versions, you can add the javafx-base module as a dependency and get access to the collections without having to pull in the entire Java FX system.

Answer (score 1):

What you are essentially asking for is a Cache which can provide event notification. There are some products out there like Infinispan that already provide that for you but without knowing your use case its hard to recommend.

If you want a simple ObservableMap it should be easy to implement. You simply have to create an Observer pattern. You can find an example [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/DesignPatternObserver/article.html).

Comment: Infinispan would be great, but i need this inside an applet, so i can deliver data to.... infinispan! Just because javascript calls are treated as unsigned code i can't deliver directly :(

Comment: Infinispan has both embedded and distributed modes. You can embed Infinispan in your JVM.