# Implement HashMap<K,ArrayList> with listener on Value i.e. ArrayList

Tags: java, collections, listener, observer-pattern

I would like a Map implementation in which i could add listeners for every time the value in the ArrayList(value part of Map) changes.

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<ImageModel>> filePaths = new HashMap<>();
if (!filePaths.containsKey(key) {
        filePaths.put(key, new ArrayList<ImageModel>());
}
filePaths.get(key).add(imageModel);//add a listener to this part
```

After going through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846365/is-there-a-map-implementation-with-listeners-for-java) and limited knowledge of Observer patterns, I am confused on how to implement this. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you mean to say you want to get notify when adding the items in listview ? using listener ?

Comment: what listview? I want to get a event trigger when `ArrayList` is changed in `HashMap<String, ArrayList<ImageModel>>`

Comment: yeah , my bad, yeah you can make broadcast receiver and when you add items just call that reciever, just like other receivers

Answer (score 1):

Amir's answer is a pretty good jumping off point for you. However, if you can manipulate the ArrayList outside of the HashMap (which it seems like you'd be able to with this question), you should probably want to wrap the ArrayList. If we tweak his answer a bit, we can get:

```
public class SpecialArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    private final Map<K, V> delegatee;

    public SpecialArrayList (Map<K, V> delegatee) {
        this.delegatee = delegatee;
    }

    public void add(int i , T value) {
        super.add(i, value);
        delegatee.actionPerformed/callBack/doTheThing/whatever
    }

    public void remove (int index) {
        super.remove(index);
        delegatee.actionPerformed/callBack/doTheThing/whatever
    }

    // rest of methods here
}
```

Then just add that actionPerformed() or callBack() or whatever you want to call it in your Map class!

Answer (score 0):

What about a callback? Extend ArrayList and give your own ArrayList the callback (constructor). Override add and remove. In add and remove you have to call super.add() and super.remove() and then callback.onListChanged().

```
public MyArrayList(MyCallback callback) {
  mCallback = callback;
}

public boolean add(E e) {
  super.add(e)
  callback.onListChanged()
}
```